# 302 redirect from WebSphere when the request has come via a load balancer

Tags: redirects, url

I have the following setup:

`HTTPS request -> AWS ALB -> Mapped to HTTP (one of two possible ports) -> Websphere 9.0.5`

This works fine, except:

When I go to my url without a trailing slash (e.g. `https://url.com/test` instead of `https://url.com/test/`), WebSphere serves a 302 redirect to `http://url.com:9082/test/`, for example, instead of honouring the original http**s** request and port. This then doesn't load because the internal http port is not accessible externally.

The original url and protocol is captured in `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers.

Is there any way to tell WebSphere to do the redirect in the way I'd expect, so the user's browser sees `https://url.com/test/`? Or, alternatively, for the application to just work without the trailing slash?

Comment: What configuration do you have in Websphere to implement this redirect?

Comment: I've not implemented anything specific - it appears to be a default configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following custom properties need to be configured in WebSphere, under `Application Servers -> ServerName -> Web Container -> Custom Properties`:

- com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort=true
- httpsIndicatorHeader=X-Forwarded-Proto
- trusthostheaderport=true

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=configuration-web-container-custom-properties for documentation